# How to display a list of sub-categories using JSON data

Tags: angular

I have a JSON array which contains a categories array. When I navigate to "/beds" in my application I want it to show a list of sub-categories, in this case "Bed Frames".  I have a `SubCategoryComponent` which is used for each sub-category, it seems pointless to have separate components for each sub-category as I'll be loading a similar page.

How can I let my `SubcategoryComponent` know that it should be loading the correct data?  When navigating to "/beds" it should load the "Bed Frames" sub-category and for "/mattresses" it should load the relevant sub-categories.

How should I iterate over this in the template?  At the moment it seems like a nested loop but surely there's a better way.

JSON returned from my service function:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Beds",
        "path": "/beds",
        "categories" : [
            "Bed Frames"
        ]
    }
]
```

Service function:

```
    getTopLevelCategories(): Observable<ITopLevelCategory[]> {
        return this.http.get<ITopLevelCategory[]>(this.topLevelCategoryUrl)
          .pipe(
            tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
            catchError(this.handleError)
          );
      }
```

Router:

```
   RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
      { path: 'beds', component: SubcategoryComponent },
      { path: 'mattresses', component: SubcategoryComponent },
    ]),
```

Comment: could you please make a stackblitz example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following:

1: add the `data` array to the route:

```
{ path: 'beds', component: SubcategoryComponent, data: {category: "/beds"} },
```

2: return the relevant top level category in the service

```
      getCategory(category: string): Observable<ITopLevelCategory | undefined> {
        return this.getTopLevelCategories()
          .pipe(
            map((toplevelcategories: ITopLevelCategory[]) => toplevelcategories.find(toplevelcategories => toplevelcategories.path === category))
          );
      }
```

3: Get the category in the component

```
  getCategory(category: string) {
    this.topLevelCategoryService.getCategory(category).subscribe({
      next: toplevelcategory => this.toplevelcategory = toplevelcategory,
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    });
  }
```

4: Output the sub-categories in the template

```
{{toplevelcategory.categories}}
```